# Vue child components not rendering according to computed functions

Tags: typescript, vue.js

In my application, I was building a dashboard component where I can display view according to the state which was served using a computed function in the component itself, but I found some unusual behaviour, the component is rendering wrong child component.

```
<template>
  <div class="dashboard-wrapper">
    <div class="dashboard-content">
      <LoaderView v-if="isViewLoading"/>
      <div v-else>
        <ActivityView v-if="currentView === 'Activity' " />
        <SubscriptionView v-if="currentView == 'Subscriptions'"/>
        <ProfileView v-if="currentView == 'Profile'"/>
        <SecurityView v-if="currentView == 'Security'"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
.
.
.
get currentView () {

    return Activity.activeView
}
.
.
.
</script>
```

Also, I checked Vue dev tools, and the state was updated accordingly.
Just to note, I checked, the child components are fine.

Comment: Make sure Activity.activeView is reactive and temporarily output it inside <div class="dashboard-content" > to mare sure it switches correctly

Comment: @Anatoly the Activity.activeView is a getter function from state module.

Comment: So you look the store in VueJs DevTools and see that currentView is correct and afterwards you look at Componenets (in DevTools) and see wrong component?

Comment: @Anatoly yes Actually I did some typo error, the prohlem is solved.  Thankyou